# Split build and unit test with Maven and Jenkinsfile without loosing jacoco test coverage

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline, jacoco, test-coverage

As a matter of personal preference I like to distinguish a separate 1) build stage and 2 unit test stage.

The reason for this is that I consider build failures far more severe than unit test failures.

I was wondering if it is possible to do this with Maven and Jenkinsfile.

Typically build and unit tests are combined in one stage

```
stage('Build & Unit Test') {

    withMaven(jdk: 'jdk-11.0.6+10', maven: 'maven-3.3.9') {
        sh "mvn clean package" 
    }

    junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'

    jacoco classPattern: '**/target/classes', \
        exclusionPattern: '**/target/lib', \
        execPattern: '**/target/**.exec', \
        inclusionPattern: '**/*.class'
}
```

My personal preference is to do something like

```
stage('Build') {

    withMaven(jdk: 'jdk-11.0.6+10', maven: 'maven-3.3.9') {
        sh "mvn install -DskipTests" 
    }
}

stage('Unit Test') {

    withMaven(jdk: 'jdk-11.0.6+10', maven: 'maven-3.3.9') {
        sh "mvn clean package" 
    }

    junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'

    jacoco classPattern: '**/target/classes', \
        exclusionPattern: '**/target/lib', \
        execPattern: '**/target/**.exec', \
        inclusionPattern: '**/*.class'
}
```

The problem then is that the test coverage becomes 0. For some reason. When I remove the Build stage, test coverage is okay. So it seems that for some reason de `-DskipTests` carries over from one stage to the next.

Is it possible to split build and unit test in stages and still keep test coverage? If so, how should this be done?

Comment: First why do you use `mvn install` on a CI system? Furthermore I see only one thing is that you are separating a thing which shouldn't be separated and makes your build in Jenkins longer than needed.  Also I recommend to take a look at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-maven/ to use more up-to-date configuration in your Jenkins like options etc. Also more up-to-date version of Maven...

Comment: So the answer is that it isn't possible. If these things are not supposed to be separated as a matter of principle as you suggest, rather than preference, why are these separated? As described https://www.baeldung.com/maven-goals-phases. Why is Maven itself separating a compile and test phase???

Comment: Technically you can separate them but what would be the advantage (apart from increasing run time on Jenkins). The separation of the llife cycle phases makes sense to bind different plugins to the appropriate phases. Apart from that the linked article only describes https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html Maven has them separated to make a separation of concern here for compile phase where compiler plugin is bound (the purpose maybe of another plugin) and the test phase as running the unit tests or for integration test where you can run IT's...